# Rsync copy directory contents but not directory itself

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to synchronize two contents of folders with different name:

```
rsync -av ~/foo user@remote.com:/var/www/bar
```

I'd like to copy the content of `foo` into `bar` at remote host, but not the directory `foo` itself. I've tried something like `foo/*`, but rsync doesn't support that.

rsync always creates

```
/var/www/bar/foo
```

Answer (score 309, accepted):

rsync interprets a directory with **no** trailing slash as `copy this directory`, and a directory **with** a trailing slash as `copy the contents of this directory`.

Try `rsync -av ~/foo/ user@remote.com:/var/www/bar/`

Comment: This behavior is odd, compared to `mv` or `cp`.

Comment: Seems weird and inconsistent to make the trailing slash relevant for just this particular command. Wonder why it hasn't been changed.

Comment: In case someone was also wondering *why* this works: it's the trailing `/` after the directory name.

Comment: I also found it odd that the -a option was needed.  If I don't use '-a' then I'll get an error skipping the directory and nothing happens.  Reading the man pages, I wouldn't have concluded that.  It seems like based on the docs that it should work without the -a option and the -v option is only for verbosity so that isn't relevant to the actual copy working.  Weird.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I'm just speculating, but it might be that in all honesty the way `*` works is pretty strange. `*` expands, so if you have many files in a directory, your command `cp src/* dest` expands into potentially a massive command. Again, all speculation, but maybe `rsync` moved away from it for this reason

Comment: This doesn't work on my machine for some reason. It still attempts to create the directory foo and as such I get a permission error.

Comment: `-a` is shorthand for `-rlptgoD`; it's possible that you need the `-r`/`--recursive` to copy directories at all. And `*` is usually a shell-side thing, not rsync; the filenames get expanded before they even hit rsync (unless you escape it with something like `rsync src/\* dest`.

Answer (score 96):

It's simple,

`rsync /var/www/ /home/var` - copies the contents of /var/www/ but not the **www** folder itself.

`rsync /var/www /home/var` - copies the folder **www** along with all its contents.

Answer (score 35):

Not related only to rsync, but when you are looking for examples on how to use a GNU/Linux command, you can use "eg" which displays explicit examples.
eg is available here, with instructions on how to install it: https://github.com/srsudar/eg

The result for `eg rsync` is as follow

```
# rsync


copy the folder source_dir and its content into destination_dir

    rsync -av source_dir destination_dir


copy the contents of source_dir (trailing slash) into destination_dir

    rsync -av source_dir/ destination_dir
```

Answer (score 3):

Navigate into the directory you would like to copy over, so:

```
cd ~/foo
```

Run this:

```
rsync -avz . user@remote.com:/var/www/bar
```