# How to use python to copy full directory and its contents overwrittenly?

Tags: python, copy

The file structure looks like this:

/email1/spam

/email2/spam

/email3/spam
...

Now, copy all files under all 'spam' directories to a new directory called /email_data/spam

I tried to use shutil.copytree, but it only copy the first directory (copytree requires the destination must not exists).

Then I tried distutils.dir_util.copy_tree, it works, but I don't know why everytime after its copy, there will be some duplicated files. (e.g. spam_email.txt, spam_email_1.txt). There should be 15045 files, but the code copy 16545 which 1500 more...

Comment: Is there any specific reason why Python is needed? Other utilities like `rsync` might be a better fit.

Comment: Yes, I have to use python to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `os.walk` and ask if the root is spam, and only then copy the file with `shutil`.

Maybe not the most efficient way, but quite reasonable.
Another way is to use `os.system`, for example with:

```
find . --path *spam | xargs -I {} cp -r {} ./spam
```

Haven't verified.

Comment: This doesn't provide a meaningful answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found rsync is very easy to use, as metatoaster said, just use os.system(*command*).

Actually distutils.dir_util.copy_tree works as well, there is no duplication error of copy, the source directory itself has duplicated files...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take the `shutil.copytree()` & `shutil.copy()` method like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419665/python-move-and-overwrite-files-and-folders) in combinatin with `rsync` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300971/rsync-copy-directory-contents-but-not-directory-itself)

Here is a not tested full example for copy pasting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput, os, fnmatch, re, io, errno, shutil
import ignore_patterns from shutil

errorMsgSrc = "Source File does exists, continuing using rsync ..."

def CopyFolder(src, dest):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            shutil.copytree(src, dest, ignore= ignore_patterns('*.json', '*.css', '*.scss', '*.js', '*.jpg', '*.png', '*.xcf'))
            print(errorMsgSrc.rstrip())
        if os.path.exists(dest):
            # Now choose your weapons for overwriting
            # maybe you wanna change working directory with e.g., os.chdir(dir)
            # -arv (archive, recursively and verbose)
            # make sure you got the slashes correct here
            assert os.system("rsync -arv " + src + " " + dest), "ERROR rsync step failed"
            # either delete the source file or use rsync with os.system

    except OSError as e:
    # If the error was caused because the source wasn't a directory
        if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dest)
        else:
            print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CopyFolder("source/", "~/home/usr/Desktop/")
```